# input and Output with math in C

Tags: c, math

Example
Input: 12345
Output: (1+2+3+4+5=15)--> (1+5=6) Output is 6
(It shoud be only one number (1-9)

Please tell me how to make sure that when you enter a number, for example 12345, the output is equal to the sum 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15 and then 1 + 5 = 6. C language. Thank you very much for your answer!

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
        int isicc;
        scanf ("%d", &isicc);
            while (isicc>0){
                int d = isicc%10;
                isicc=isicc /10;
            }
           
        printf ("Your number ", d);
           
    }
```

Comment: Does it compile? What is the message of the compiler? Where is calculated the sum?

Comment: Well, what happens when you printf out 'd' in the loop?   Does it look useful?  Maybe you should add it to some accumulator int variable?  Why do you not just do what you want?

Comment: Because I don't know how to do this. I am only trying

Comment: You need to get the steps right first.  Draw a flowchart and follow it by hand, first.  (hint: two nested loops).  Then you can concentrate on expressing it with the correct syntax and nuances.

Answer (score 0):

After the command

```
scanf ("%d", &isicc);
```

You can use this code to get the sum of digits of the number:

```
int sum_digits = 0;
while (isicc > 0) {
    sum_digits += isicc % 10;
    isicc = isicc / 10;
}
isicc = sum_digits;
```

Now, you just need to repeat this process in another loop , that will continue as long as isicc is bigger than 9.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stlib.h>    
#include <stdio.h>
        int main(){
            int isicc;
            scanf ("%d", &isicc);
               
            isicc = abs(isicc);
            printf ("Your number %d\n", isicc?isicc%9?isicc%9:9:0 );
               
        }
```

Comment: is that really the same?

Comment: @JDługosz:  I believe it provides the same output.   The teacher may not like the calculation method. (Hah!)  But the output should be correct.

Comment: It will work correctly for numbers in the range 0-99. But for example for 180 it will return 0, while it should be 9. Also, the result of: num % 9 can never be 9. Maybe the correct formula is something similar?

Answer (score -2):

Try this program, it will add digits and print sum

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main ()
 {
    int num,n,sum=0;
    printf ("Enter number:");
    scanf (" %d",&num);
   while (num!=0){
        n=num%10;
        sum += n;
        num = num/10;
    }
    printf ("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This line is gibberish: `scanf ("enter the numbers:= %d",&num);`  You do NOT put the prompt in the `scanf` function call.   Even after fixing the `scanf`, the rest of the program gives bad output.  For input `12345`, it outputs `15`. The correct answer is `6`.

Comment: From the OP:  *"1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15 and then 1 + 5 = 6"*

Comment: Okay, I got it. Can you please let me know how your code is working?